# Как сгладить плавный скролл к якорной ссылке?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Всем привет.
Использую скрипт для плавной прокрутки к якорю:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');

   for (let anchor of anchors) {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         let blockID = anchor.getAttribute('href').substr(1);

         document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start'
         });
      });
   };
});
```

У скролла присутствует плавность, но скорость прокрутки получается большая, особенно если перемещение происходит с самого верха страницы к самому последнему якорю.

Каким образом я могу сгладить, сделать плавнее прокрутку?

Читал что-то про кадры при прокрутке, но решения не нашел.